# Export Excel chart and then Delete the file

Tags: c#, excel, export, delete-file

I am using C# to export an Excel chart and then delete the exported file at a later stage in the program.

However, I get the error "The process cannot access the file 's:\VS Programs\Contouring_rev\contouring_dem.bmp' because it is being used by another process." error.

Here is my code;

```
chartPage.Export(@"s:\\VS Programs\\Contouring_rev\\contouring_dem.bmp", "BMP", misValue);
.
.
.
if (File.Exists(@"s:\\VS Programs\\Contouring_rev\\contouring_dem.bmp"))
{
    File.Delete(@"s:\\VS Programs\\Contouring_rev\\contouring_dem.bmp");
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a close or dispose on the chartPage? Try setting it to null as well. If you are using a Winforms application, add an Application.DoEvents() to ensure the chartPage is finished doing it's thing before trying to delete.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** It might be garbage collection issue

```
System.GC.Collect(); 
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); 
File.Delete(filePath);
```

Comment: Still the same error. I guess it is the export process (the one that converts the chart into a bitmap image) that remains open. If so, do you know how I can tackle that one? Thanks